# Order of Convergence when working with errors

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, standard-error, rate-of-convergence

I am looking at the numerical solutions of a problem when using the boundary element method, the exact solution is 0.25

I have 3 errors corresponding to using 20,40 and 80 boundary elements.

I have seen online the order of convergence for discretisation methods uses formula:
$$ q = \frac{log(E_1/E_0)}{log(h_1/h_0)} $$
where $q$ is the order of convergence, $E_1 , E_0$ are the errors and $h_1,h_0$ are step sizes. I do not understand what the step sizes would be in this case.

I thought I would look at getting two values for q using error 1 and error 2 (using $h_1 =40, h_0 =20$) but I end up with a negative $q$ which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could you please give a hint on the exact nature of your problem and what the "boundary element method" is? In general the step size would be inverse proportional to the number of segments, so instead of $h_1/h_0$ you could also use $N_0/N_1$. This should just remove the sign from your previous result.

Comment: I am using a numerical method called the boundary element method to find the solution to the Laplace equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions on a circular domain. So I get a numerical solution T based on the number of elements (20,40 or 80) the boundary is discretised by. But I know the analytical answer is T= 0.25. For 20 elements I get T=0.2466... this value T gets closer to 0.25 for 40  elements then for 80 elements. So my thought process was if I can show q is the same for using the error with 20 elements and 40 elements compared with the error for 40 elements and 80 elements, then...

Comment: I would have found my order of convergence